# How to access variable value out of an abstract call in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to access outside variable values in Abstract class.
I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. The following code shows what I tried to do so far.

```
  <?php
    require_once 'config.php';

    abstract class connect {
        protected $link;
        public function __construct($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname2) {

            $host = $dbhost;
            $user = $dbuser;
            $password = $dbpass;
            $database = $dbname2;
            // $host = 'localhost';
            // $user = 'student';
            // $password = 'c@18504';
            // $database = 'practice';
            $this->link = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
            if(!mysqli_connect_errno()) {

            } else {
                die("connection error: ".  mysqli_connect_error());

            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here, combine 2 strings or add them up? `"value1"` and `"value2"` are strings.

Comment: what are the actual values of `$a` and `$b` ?

Comment: no i am not trying .. i am doing practice. i am facing this problem. that's why i am asking you.

Comment: any value like $a = 2 and $b = 2 anything

Comment: This code smells bad. Global variables should never be used inside a class like this.  Pass them into the constructor, or if you REALLY need to, use `define()` to create a constant. Or, if these vars are only used in the class, define them as class properties.  More importantly are you sure you need an abstract class here?

Comment: You can't return anything from a [constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php); and you can't instantiate an [abstract class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php), you need a concrete class that extends it first, and neither $a nor $b are [in scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) within the class method

Comment: Check it above i have changed in my question. variable stored in config.php

Answer (score -1):

First as many have said you cannot instantiate an `abstract class` no way. My guess is not much will be extending this so I will go the route of you just want a class (if I am wrong let me know and I will update)

```
class connect {}
```

What you are doing is not for a constructor. That is more of a mutator. I will assume you do not have these as properties and just want to pass them in so create a `class` `method` to do this

```
class connect {
    public function sumOfTwoNum($a, $b){
        return $a + $b;
    }
}

$conn = new connect();
$a = 15;
$b = 2;
echo $conn->sumOfTwoNum($a, $b); //17

//The variable names do not matter and in fact are not needed.
//$a and $b are for the scope of the function
echo $conn->sumOfTwoNum(8, 5); //13
```

Now lets assume you want a `constructor` you can set `class` `properties` and then use them in other methods with the `$this`.

```
class connect {
    public $a, $b;
    public function __construct($a, $b) {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }
    public function sumOfTwoNum(){
        return $this->a + $this->b;
    }
}

$conn = new connect(12, 15);
echo $conn->sumOfTwoNum(); //27
// Since $a and $b are public you can set them
$conn->a = 2;
echo $conn->sumOfTwoNum(); //17
//If these were private you would need to create getter/setters.
```